# What is com.android.documentsui

Tags: applications

This shows in my Google web activity.  Does anyone know what this does?

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

A simple [Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q="com.android.documentsui") answers that: it's a "file picker" introduced with Kitkat (Android 4.4) and since Lollipop (Android 5) the recommended default interfact for apps wishing to access files outside of their own storage area (i.e. to save data to your SD card). It ships with the Android system itself – so no worries, it's nothing malicious.